# Get Value of closest input Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i click on id save_newsection i need value of class school_name means school name

```
<div class="school_form_submit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">School Name<span class="required"> * </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control school_name" placeholder="Please Enter School Name" value="dfghdf" name="school_name_submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" id="save_newsection" class="btn green">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one input with the class `.school_name`, use this

```
$("#save_newsection").click(function() {
    var value = $("input.school_name").val();
    // use value
});
```

If there could be more of them throughout the document use this:

```
$("#save_newsection").click(function() {
    var value = $(".school_form_submit .school_name").val();
    // use value
});
```

```js
$("#save_newsection").click(function() {
    var value = $(".school_form_submit .school_name").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school_form_submit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">School Name
      <span class="required"> * </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control school_name" placeholder="Please Enter School Name" value="dfghdf" name="school_name_submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" id="save_newsection" class="btn green">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: its show me  undefined i am using second method because i have school name dynamic

Comment: closest not valid here

Comment: prev()? how can you please type here

Comment: @charlietfl yeah! I edited the question after I posted the answer! It was a mess!

Comment: probably a modal class above that would have worked with closest though

Comment: `.school_form_submit .school_name` will do!

Comment: its not working 
$(document).on('click', '#save_newsection', function () {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().find(".school_name").val();
  alert(value);
});

Comment: @sagarparmar `.prev` depends on a lot of stuff. I told you to check the new answer above! I don't use `.prev`!

Comment: var value = $(".school_form_submit .school_name").val(); this answer give me undefined

Comment: @sagarparmar then check the HTML code you post it in the question! It's wrong! Because the code snippet above work just fine!

Comment: there are many school_form_submit class in my coding thats why i can not use that working code

Comment: @sagarparmar Just add a unique class or ID to that element.

Comment: bro its not possible all thing is dynamic

Comment: any possible way to find using closest and nearest or any other jquery function

Comment: @sagarparmar does the `.modal-footer` where your button is, is just after the `.school_form_submit` where the input is?

Comment: @sagarparmar im agree with ibrahim, he's answer is correct. the wrong thing is your question. anyway try this http://jsbin.com/fumeduq , there i just copy your element 2 times, and i still get the right value.

Comment: thanks friends its working now Thank you very much for your time